# Are questions that are only loosely related to gaming on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Here is a thing. Look at the thing. Do you see the thing? I would like to know what this Thing is Called.” A plea for sanity](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5081/here-is-a-thing-look-at-the-thing-do-you-see-the-thing-i-would-like-to-know)

In questions like [What is the genre of music in Katamari called?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/100174/what-is-the-genre-of-music-in-katamari-called) and [Who sings 'Embrace the Heresy'?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/79991/who-sings-embrace-the-heresy) where the main question is not about a problem the asker has, but about a feature that is unknown to the OP.

How should we treat questions like this?

Comment: I think this was somewhat covered [here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/5081/6066).

Comment: Agree with you @MatthewRead didn't saw that question before.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, those type of question should be treated like the [game-identification](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-identification).

References links:

- [What is the point of “help me remember this game” questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1455/what-is-the-point-of-help-me-remember-this-game-questions)
- [Call for concepts: Determining new “Identify This Game” criteria](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4124/call-for-concepts-determining-new-identify-this-game-criteria)
- [What should be done with questions asking for game identification?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4168/what-should-be-done-with-questions-asking-for-game-identification) (take a good look at the why it should and why it should not)

Comment: You should probably actually write how you propose they be treated instead of linking to the endless and confusing arguments.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot sorry. I though that as they are meta links, I didn't have to. going to make an edit asap =)