# Is there any way to link to a specific part of a question/answer?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

So, going through all the Minecraft crash questions, I've noticed that quite a few has been already covered [in this Community Wiki post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/is-there-a-list-of-error-codes-for-minecraft?s=3%7C1.7259).

However, simply marking it as duplicate for that post isn't enough as it brings them to the very top of the page.
From experience, I've also noticed that some of these people do not know how to talk proper English... So - Presuming (not implying that) they're idiots who don't know how to find information...

Plus it makes hyperlinking easier for long questions, that may contain information for other things... I mean; it's not like it's convinenent when someone tells you: "Your information is in this [1000-page] book... Somewhere.."

### Is there any way to link to a specific part or header in a page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To directly answer your question: No, duplicate links are generated to point to the question as a whole, and the best we could do is point it at the full-answer, not subsection or headers of it.

**However**, We're actually [in the process](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10421/28182) of trying to move away from having that one giant Q&A to a bunch of smaller, problem-specific questions and answers to aid people when they are searching and (hopefully) helping them finding the problem quicker (and in time, slow down the new questions being created).

We're planning on doing this by giving questions descriptive titles and bodies that should help raise these questions to the top of the results list when searched using a Search Engine such as Google. This process of optimising for search is called, funnily enough, *Search Engine Optimisation* (or SEO).

Not only will this benefit the users looking for solutions, but helps push Arqade into the forefront and allows us to reach more people overall.