# A chain of duplicate Minecraft questions

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Today, this question ablout Minecraft was asked: [Minecraft EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) [ig8icd64.dll+0x16b87]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/286346/exception-access-violation-0xc0000005) (**-2** net votes, asked today, 9/25/2016)

it was put on hold as off-topic because it *seemed* to be about modded Minecraft crashing. But as the OP said later, his Minecraft crashes even when without mods. I was about to put a flag to reopen, but I realised that it is actually a duplicate of [Minecraft java EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION in Windows 7?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28836/minecraft-java-exception-access-violation-in-windows-7?rq=1) (4 net votes, asked **8/27/2011**)

When I went to that question, it said it's a duplicate of [Minecraft crashes with "EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191360/minecraft-crashes-with-exception-access-violation-0xc0000005) (2 net votes, asked **11/11/2014**)

And that question is a duplicate of [Minecraft Forge 1.7.10 keeps crashing as soon as I launch the game with EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/178772/minecraft-forge-1-7-10-keeps-crashing-as-soon-as-i-launch-the-game-with-exceptio) (2 net votes, asked **7/31/2014**)

And finally, the question ablove is a duplicate (merged) of this question: [Minecraft crashes on launch with EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION, Problematic frame: ig4dev32.dll or ig4dev64.dll or ig4icd32.dll or ig4icd64.dll](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/213699/minecraft-crashes-on-launch-with-exception-access-violation-problematic-frame) (**20** net votes, asked **4/12/2015**, protected and not marked as a duplicate)

What should I flag for moderator attention, or do something else?

Will/can anybody do something with this - like, close all four questions as a duplicate of the last one listed? Or, close all as a duplicate of the 2nd question listed, becuase it was the first one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate chain resolved

#### Master Question:

**[Minecraft crashes on launch with EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION, Problematic frame: ig4dev32.dll or ig4dev64.dll or ig4icd32.dll or ig4icd64.dll](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/213699/28182)**

#### Duplicates:

- [Minecraft EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) [ig8icd64.dll+0x16b87]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/286346/28182)
- [Minecraft java EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION in Windows 7?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28836/28182)
- [Minecraft crashes with "EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)"](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191360/28182)
- [Minecraft Forge 1.7.10 keeps crashing as soon as I launch the game with EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/178772/28182)

---

(I actually raised this a [while back](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10421/minecraft-crash-question-duplicates-and-seo/10436#10436) before I was mod, but forgot all about it).

Answer (score 0):

You can flag for moderator attention and explain what is going on and a moderator can change the paths for the duplicate, you can create a meta post like you have done now and explain what is going on, or, if you catch one in chat, you can ask them if they have time to help you with it. Any of these options are valid, though some moderators prefer to have a meta post or mod flag to reference as opposed to being asked about it in chat, that way when they have time they can examine things in a little more structured manner and decide which duplicate targets need to be fixed.