# Is it appropriate to flag old modded Minecraft crash questions?

Tags: discussion, flags

The recent meta discussion [Minecraft crash questions should be made off-topic: yes/no?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10390/minecraft-crash-questions-should-be-made-off-topic-yes-no) has decided that technical support for *modded* Minecraft is now off-topic.

We seem to be removing new questions on this topic rather well. However, there is still a large backlog of questions dating **before** this was off-topic, and are now just laying around.

I really want to help clean up. So I have a few questions:

1. Are these old questions going to be closed? Or are we keeping them open?
2. If we are going to close them, is it appropriate to go along and start flagging them myself? Or will high rep users/diamond mods be doing this in bulk?

Comment: In general, Flag/Vote if you see a problem, *but don't go searching for one.* As of the last week or so, the close queues are getting a few of the older modded tech support questions in dribs and drabs, but no drastic overarching effort is taking place.

Comment: Flags are reserved for actions that *require* moderator intervention. Can you do what you want to do (just closing questions?) without mod powahs? If so, please don't use flags.

Comment: @fredley No, I don't have access to the close/reopen queues.

Comment: Yes, but any user over 3k reputation does (and we have plenty of those). Perhaps a better forum for raising the neccessary close votes would be [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge), rather than mod flags. At time of writing, there are ~285 users with >3k rep, and 7 mods.

Comment: @fredley on SO  it seems that "close" flags go to review queues rather than mods, is the same not true here? (Or do you not have the tools for filtering the flag queue?)

Comment: @TZHX Oh, that's probably true. We've had an influx of "Other" flags requesting closure recently. This is a trend I don't want to continue.

Comment: @fredley I see. Totally agree tisn't a suitable use of an "other" flag.

Comment: @fredley I agree with TZHX. I generally use the 'Totally off-topic' flag for this issue rather than mod attention flags.  But is this the right flag, since we don't have a custom close reason yet? Also, is it appropriate if I go flagging these questions with these flags?

Answer (score 1):

We're [looking at another approach](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10609/a-potentially-better-way-of-dealing-with-crash-report-questions) to the problem entirely. There's a few important things to note about these:

1. Their presence alone encourages more of the same
2. Mods, along with high-rep users are just *sick* of looking at them
3. Support for modded Minecraft is okay, *once your game actually loads*. Some are interpreting it to mean that we only answer questions about Vanilla, which would be an enormous mistake.

As we progress on smarter ways of just not *accepting* most of these, I'm planning on running some queries to identify them, and take most of them out back for silent, humane dispatching. Once the blacklist entries are firmly in place, folks won't even be able to *edit* the old ones, so they really need to go.

But, let's not bury individuals in minutiae when we've got bulldozers on the way :)

Comment: Yeah, I have had a look at this pot already. I think it's a good idea, similar to [MrLemon's post.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10421/minecraft-crash-question-duplicates-and-seo) But still wondering if this is appropriate.

Comment: They're like tribbles, really the only word I have to describe them. They also, due to their nature, don't age particularly well given how fast the mods, forge, and game itself tend to move. It's to the point now where the oldest (circa 1.6.4) aren't only off-topic, but have lost any relevance that they might have had. (Disclaimer: I play a ton of Minecraft)

Comment: Is the third point still valid?