# Site scope for game technical questions

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, scope

When I read [**this question**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223378/recover-skyrim-saved-game-from-condemned-computer) (which is in the hot network list as I'm writing this question), my first reaction was that it was off-topic, and should be on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Yet, I saw that the highest voted answer to this question was by a moderator, who clearly does not agree with me that this is a SuperUser question. Ultimately, the question is "how do I recover a file from a computer that has been infected by a virus" - which has nothing to do with the fact that the file is a Skyrim game save.

I understand that technical issues (like [crash issues](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10609/a-potentially-better-way-of-dealing-with-crash-report-questions)) would be considered on topic in some situations, specifically, when the question is really about *that particular game*. Can someone clarify for me why [the linked question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223378/recover-skyrim-saved-game-from-condemned-computer) is on topic? More generally, what are the rules for the SuperUser / Arqade overlap questions? Which ones should be migrated, which shouldn't, and why?

Comment: The question, other than the "Can a Skyrim save be infected by a virus" part, is off-topic.  As a quick test, if you can remove the game from the question without affecting it, it is off-topic here.

Comment: Actually, the more I look at, the question is OK.  The answer does move outside of our purview a bit, but that isn't a reason to toss it all out.

Comment: So the core of the question is 'can I move a save file using a USB stick'. Answer is an easy yes, but I'd consider it irresponsible not to provide the extra info in my answer, given the opportunities for transmitting a virus to everything else via a USB stick!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linked question is not just asking "how do I recover a file from a computer that has been infected by a virus?" In fact, since they describe the procedure for doing that in the question (" copy the saved games file, put it on a pendrive"), they don't seem to be asking that at all. Rather, what they seem to be asking is "*If* I copy the saved game file, will I be able to use it after reformatting the computer and reinstalling the game", which is specific to Skyrim.

Comment: It's also very much worth asking, since the answer is not automatically "yes".  SimIsle for MS-DOS, for example, has files besides the savegame file that you may need to copy.