# Should we remove the Minecraft mod tags?

Tags: discussion, minecraft

As of this year, we only support questions about the vanilla version of Minecraft. However, when [searching through the tags](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags) typing in "Minecraft" quickly reveals we have a plethora of tags related to Minecraft-mod specific questions (such as 'minecraft-direwolf20', 'minecraft-industrialcraft,' 'minecraft-comes-alive,' 'minecraft-voltz,' the list goes on).

This means that when a new user comes to add a question to the site and are asked to tag it, suggested tags come up for the different mods. It would be pretty easy for these users to assume that mod questions are allowed when we have specific tags already created for them.

To combat this problem and to somewhat more discourage the asking of Minecraft mod questions, I was wondering if we should remove these Minecraft mod tags. I'm not quite sure how we would go about this (changing all the tags manually might be a pain), but I still think it's something that might want to be addressed.

**EDIT:** Okay, okay sorry I messed up. I read [these](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/249738/my-minecraft-mods-are-not-working-on-my-pc) question comments which led me to the answer of [this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10390/minecraft-crash-questions-should-be-made-off-topic-yes-no). So with that incorrect perception I mis-read [this tag wiki](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/minecraft-forge/info). My bad, I didn't realize questions actual about Minecraft mods were allowed. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Mod questions *are* allowed.

Comment: Oh boy here come the downvotes....

Answer (score 6):

**No**. Gameplay questions about modded Minecraft are, and have always been, on-topic. The decision you are referring to specifically mentions *technical support* questions being disallowed (which as far as I'm aware, [we are limiting that to mean crashes](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11015/what-exactly-is-technical-support))

Therefore, we should not remove tags in an effort to discourage users from asking questions about modded Minecraft, since only a particular category of modded Minecraft questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no reason to remove the tags, as we still support modded Minecraft questions, just not ones that are basically "this doesn't work, I have a bajillion mods, be my tech support", which usually come in the form of a crash dump and not much else.

People are still allowed to ask about various mods and how they work and all of that, so the tags are still very much needed and useful to sort these types of questions.