# The 'What topics can I ask about here?' Help Center page is out of date

Tags: discussion, status-completed, allowed-questions, help-center

The [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) currently only lists the following topics as off-topic:

> - Game and Mod Development (try the Game Development Stack Exchange instead)
> - Speculative questions about developer intent, with respect to both mechanics and narrative
> - Requests for game identification based on personal recollection alone
> - Catalogues (listing games that fit specific criteria or are like an existing game)
> - Shopping advice and recommendations
> - Speculation of the future of the industry and of upcoming releases
> - Piracy, and support with pirated games.

In April we decided that [technical support for modded Minecraft is now off-topic](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10390/minecraft-crash-questions-should-be-made-off-topic-yes-no/). As such we have closed [quite a few<sup>1</sup>](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=[minecraft*]%20closed%3Ayes%20crash) questions, but we still get some questions since the only explanatory posts are on meta.

**All the other off-topic reasons are there, so why isn't this one?**

Comment: my understanding is that the center acts as a guide. As a community, we go into more detail, add inclusions, and define our understanding of on/off topic. For example, any question asking about developer intent is off topic. However, the help center lists **developer speculation**, which does not include asking about developer intent **with the inclusion of proven material**.

Comment: Questions tagged with [meta-tag:faq] on meta are considered to be community-defined rules. [How do I ask a good Minecraft Bug/Crash question?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/9943/28182) was updated to include a reference to the fact that technical support modded Minecraft is off-topic, and the step for 'list your mods' was removed. There could be a case made to have the entire [ruling](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/10390/28182) made `[faq]` but that's up to the mod's discretion(s).

Comment: While we are at it, shopping advice can include a link to hardwarerecommendations.se.