# Why was this question closed as "unclear"?

Tags: discussion, closing

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/331270/minecraft-lag-spikes-every-5-mins) was closed as "unclear what you're asking" despite me pointing out earlier in the comments that "too broad" was the correct close reason. If it all, because shortly afterwards OP delivered specs, settings, crash report and other info.

In general I often see "unclear" being used where "too broad" would be appropriate. Why is that the case? Do people just not care about close reasons or is there really something they don't understand about these questions?
And should this question be reopened now that it contains additional info? Is "unclear" just a way of people saying "this probably can't have a proper answer"? In that case every second question in [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues) would have to be closed as "unclear".

Comment: As a side note, I voted as Unclear because there's not enough info in the question to answer it. Comments don't count.

Comment: I agree with @Frank .. there were simply not enough details to answer the question before it was edited and it still lacks some. Lag spikes with no further details (PC specs, settings, etc)? How are we supposed to know where they come from? A good answer to the original question would be a miracle... or *very* long if you included all possibilities. And yes, it could probably be  reopened now since we now have some specs to work with

Answer (score -1):

There was a [discussion in the past about how to handle Minecraft crash content](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10390/minecraft-crash-questions-should-be-made-off-topic-yes-no) on the site.  It was determined that we do not attempt to resolve crash related issues with modded Minecraft.

Comment: That's not at all what that question is about. The only time there was a crash was with my instructions. The only time there was a mod involved was when he didn't have the problem.

Comment: Then the question can probably be saved with some editing.  I personally didn't vote to close this one, but it seems to be a knee-jerk reaction to questions that contain 'minecraft', 'mods', and 'crash'.

Comment: If it's really a crash in modded Minecraft, it's just offtopic.