# Can we ask about the specifics of mod incompatibility?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, minecraft

So we know that asking about mod related minecraft issues are off topic, but I was wondering if it was more specific, would that be on topic?

For example; "I am using mod X and mod Y in my Minecraft which appear to be incompatible; how can I find out why?"

Answer (score 5):

My answer is no, this question isn't allowed. Check out the [top answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10391/163757) on the post that is linked in our [on topic help page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> **Mods are constantly in conflict with Vanilla, and each other.** Minecraft mods override base functionality. Other mods might also override that same base functionality. This potentially makes them incompatible, or cause crashes when vanilla Minecraft expects a particular value but gets another.
> This is a problem whether or not modders list their incompatibilities with other mods - because if two things exist then someone, somewhere, someday will find an excuse to try and put them together. And it's up to us to know about every mods incompatibilities (or know how/where to find a list of them, if it exists).